# trying to build my ionic application with --prod but it doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i tried the whole time to build my project with `ionic build android --prod` but i get always the same error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAacr.png)

and when i add `IonicApp` to my `App.Module.ts` then i get following **error:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHMS3.png)

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
  OverlayPortal,
  ClickBlock,
  EventsfilterComponent,
  FooterComponent,
  ImgWithSpinnerComponent,
  NotificationsComponent,
  SpotifyComponent,
  IonicApp
  ],
 imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
      backButtonText: '',
      backButtonIcon: 'ios-arrow-back',
      scrollPadding: false
  },),
  ComponentsModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  IonicImageViewerModule,
AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  AngularFireAuthModule,
  NotificationsPageModule,
  HttpModule,
  ConversationPageModule,
  EventPageModule,
  GroupPageModule,
  InteractionsPageModule,
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
  SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: '__mydb',
     driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
}),
  PipesModule


Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.4.4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 5.0.3, ios 5.0.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, 
(and 30 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 0.3.0)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/leonardoprivat/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-sim           : 8.0.2
NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 6.9.0
OS                : macOS Mojave
Xcode             : Xcode 11.0 Build version 11A420aenter code here
```

Any Idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Your second error shows that ```IonicApp``` is part of 2 modules. So either remove it from whichever child module its in & leave it in the parent AppModule or create a shared module with the IonicApp component.

Comment: yeah but the thing is that IonicApp is a part of a node module, i cant remove it from there.